# Question about Mann-Whitney implementation in Mma

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

So, I've been doing some statistics using Mma. Typically, the Mann-Whitney U test is used to compare non-normally distributed samples, whose medians are compared *if* both distributions exhibit similar shapes, or otherwise you may end up comparing quantiles vs medians or other distribution properties. However, the only assumption (in univariate cases) stated in the docummentation is:

> For univariate samples MannWhitneyTest performs the Mann[Dash]Whitney U-test for median differences of independent samples. A correction for ties is applied for both asymptotic and permutation-based p-values. By default, the test statistic is corrected for continuity and **is assumed to follow a NormalDistribution**.

### My questions are:

1. I am probably misinterpreting this, but shouldn't this assumption be disregarded in here, since we are using this test to compare non-normally distributed samples?
2. Is the shape of both samples compared in any way?

### Here is a small working example and some tests

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[.1, 1], 1000];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1000];
data3 = RandomVariate[LaplaceDistribution[0, 1], 1000];

(*data1 and data2 have similar shapes:*)
KolmogorovSmirnovTest[data1, data2] 
QuantilePlot[data1, data2]
```

> 0.722555
>
> [image]

```
(*but data1 and data3 do not*)
KolmogorovSmirnovTest[data1, data3]
QuantilePlot[data1, data2]
```

> 0.00389581
>
> [image]

Since what I am interested in doing is to compare medians of the two populations, it is more relevant to do a `LocationTest` and `MannWhitneyTest`:

```
(*data1 vs data2. It is expected that LocationTest[] may test using parametric tests because both samples have normal distributions. MannWhitney test should pass because they also exhibit similar shapes*)
{Median@#[[1]], Median@#[[2]], MannWhitneyTest[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}],LocationTest[{#[[1]], #[[2]]},Automatic, {"TestDataTable", All}]} &@{data1, data2}
```

> [image]

```
(*data1 vs data3. It is expected that LocationTest[] tests using non-parametric tests because one of the samples has non-normal distribution. MannWhitney test should not pass because both samples do not exhibit similar shapes*)
{Median@#[[1]], Median@#[[2]], MannWhitneyTest[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}],LocationTest[{#[[1]], #[[2]]},Automatic, {"TestDataTable", All}]} &@{data1, data3}
```

> [image]

I would expect that the last code would not select the `MannWhitneyTest[]` given that both shapes are not similar. But this doesn't seem to be one of the assumptions of the test by default.

Could someone please clarify if the shape assumption is considered and/or tested by `MannWhitneyTest` by default?
Thanks in advance

Comment: For the null hypothesis the probability distribution of U is *symmetric* about the mean mn/2.  I don't think the assumption for normality is necessary.  Source: Nonparametric Statistical Inference 5th Edition pp 261-274.

Comment: Now, I also see that when ties are introduced, the common definition of the Mann-Whitney Statistic needs to be modified (i.e. the variance is conditional upon the observed ties).  A STANDARDIZED U is asymptotically normally distributed.

Comment: I'm more worried about the fact that no mention is done to shape of the distributions. In `LocationTest[]` there is testing on equal variance, simmetry and normality, but not on shape. This should easily be done by the `KolmogorovSmirnovTest[]` as I mentioned above and, if fails, the Welch t-test could be applied (as suggested in other places). I am unsure whether 1.shape is even tested, and therefore the reported p-values are not meaningful comparisons of *medians* and 2.if the Welch t-test is even implemented.

Comment: I had already raised the issue of Welch's t-test implementation in Mathematica in cross-validated (see: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176785/comparison-of-medians-in-samples-with-unequal-variance-size-and-shape)

Comment: in the documentation all i found was this "For univariate samples MannWhitneyTest performs the Mann\[Dash]Whitney U-test for median differences of independent samples. A correction for ties is applied for both asymptotic and permutation-based p-values. By default, the test statistic is corrected for continuity and is assumed to follow a NormalDistribution."

Comment: (eh, I had also posted that same quote in the thread above :P ) Indeed, nothing is mentioned regarding any other assumptions, but it is known that the shape of both distributions should be tested prior to the comparison of medians. I was hoping that I could be misinterpreting this issue of shape due to my lack of statistical knowledge, or that something internally was going on without being explicited in the documentation

Comment: I think we've answered the question "Could someone please clarify if the shape assumption is considered and/or tested by MannWhitneyTest by default?".  The answer is no.  MannWhitneyTest does not test the shape assumption by default.  There is the Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test for Two Independent Samples that will tell you if two independent samples represent two different populations.  I swear I read that you were using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov to do just that, but now I don't see it.

Comment: From the Handbook of Parametric and Nonparametric Statistical Procedures - I see that "As a general rule, proponents of nonparametric tests take the position that when a researcher has reason to believe the normality assumption of the t-test for two independent samples has been saliently violated, the Mann-Whitney U test provides a powerful test of the comparable alternative hypothesis".

Comment: @StevenAnderson regarding your first comment: indeed, it is a bit above (probably hidden in the comments). I think you are right, but if that is the case the documentation for `MannWhitneyTest` should clearly state it, and in cases where that is violated it should do the comparison of ranks (see below).
Regarding your second comment: indeed, that is the case! But, as you can see here and other places, one important assumption is similarity of shape (Assumption #4: https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/mann-whitney-u-test-using-spss-statistics.php).

Comment: ...if this is the case, then the documentation for `MannWhitneyTest` shouldn't state that `tests whether the medians of data1 and data2 are equal.` but rather `tests whether the medians (or U ranks) of data1 and data2 are equal`.

Comment: Don't know where you got the "medians" thing but Mann-Whitney isn't about medians.  You are also confusing non-normality of the samples and asymptotic normality of the test statistic.  This is a topic best addressed at CrossValidated as implementation in Mathematica doesn't seem to be an issue for you.  (One could relatively easily construct the exact distribution for the Mann-Whitney U in Mathematica, under the null hypothesis of identical continuous distributions but that's not your question.)

Comment: @JimBaldwin - the medians thing comes from, among other places, the documentation for `MannWhitneyTest` (link: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MannWhitneyTest.html)

Comment: The main issue of this topic is whether the assumptions of the Mann Whitney U test *for comparison of medians* are being met by Mathematica, that's why I posted this here. I hope I'm not misinterpreting anything!

Comment: Bummer.  Maybe Wolfram should hire me to clean up the statistics components of their manuals.  You're interpreting what the documentation says just fine.  It's just too bad it is not quite accurate in this case.  It's not a major sin but then, again, software manuals are not always the best place to learn statistical theory.  (There's only so much space in a manual.)

Comment: @JimBaldwin Could you please come to the chat room if you don't mind? And thanks!

Comment: @JimBaldwin or, if you prefer, feel free to add an answer! I'm sure that, even if you point for some bug or issue with implementation, it will be constructive!

Comment: I've also been stumbling against the documentation for Mann Whitney, as a non-statistician mathematician who has to teach some stats. The manual entry for M-W is structured entirely around medians (or sometimes means) so it seems more than just a little inaccurate.  I also find some discrepancies between published tables and MMA computed p-values, so a very clear manual entry would be extremely helpful.